# OLE DB provider [OraOLEDB.Oracle] for linked server [ORA] returned message ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I am having some issues with OPENQUERY.

I have this simple Linked Server SQL:

```
SELECT [ITEM_SERIAL].[SERIAL_NO]
       , [ITEM_SERIAL].[SUB_SEQ_NO_FIRM]
       , [ITEM_SERIAL].[ITEM_NO]
FROM [ORA]..[SSDIGICO].[ITEM_SERIAL]
ORDER BY [ITEM_SERIAL].[SERIAL_NO]
```

This runs smooth, no problem...

Now I am trying to use the OPENQUERY approach to improve performance such as:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORA,'
    SELECT [ITEM_SERIAL].[SERIAL_NO]
       , [ITEM_SERIAL].[SUB_SEQ_NO_FIRM]
       , [ITEM_SERIAL].[ITEM_NO]
    FROM [SSDIGICO].[ITEM_SERIAL]
    ORDER BY [ITEM_SERIAL].[SERIAL_NO]
')
```

And for some reason I get the following error message:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORA" returned
>   message "ORA-00936: missing expression". Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2,
>   Line 1 An error occurred while preparing the query "

Does any one got a clue as to why I get this error?

THANKS.

Comment: Have you tried removing the square brackets around the table/columns?  Oracle does not use square brackets.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer, feel free to accept if you want. :)

Comment: Will do BlueFeet, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not use square brackets around the tables or columns. The code should be:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORA,'
    SELECT ITEM_SERIAL.SERIAL_NO
       , ITEM_SERIAL.SUB_SEQ_NO_FIRM
       , ITEM_SERIAL.ITEM_NO
    FROM SSDIGICO.ITEM_SERIAL
    ORDER BY ITEM_SERIAL.SERIAL_NO
')
```